# Coding Graham's scan algorithm to find convex hull enclosing a set of points. I'm not able to understand the logic behind the left/right turns

Tags: algorithm

I have been referring to http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/convex-hull-set-2-graham-scan/

To see if we make a right or left turn during scan, what is being done essentially is

Given points p, q, r if (Slope of p-q) - (Slope of q-r) > 0, it is considered to be clockwise turn. if < 0, then it is considered an anti-clockwise turn.

I'm getting back to Maths after a long time. Can anyone please explain how the logic for left/right turn works ?

Comment: Have you read about cross product properties. `orientation` function uses cross product sign, not mythical slope (it is not mentioned in the link)

Comment: Thanks for responding. Looks like my interpretation was wrong. I've heard about cross product but it would be better if you could suggest a reference that I can read from